# How to create two projects in eclipse to point to one source folder

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, gradle

I have **multiple project** source which I checkout from SVN and put in project **one**
I want project **two** to point to specific part from these sources and
project **three** to another part of the sources from this multiple project.
How can I do that in eclipse ?
So when I make a change in project two, when say SVN synchronize on project one to see that the sources have been changed.
PS. I use gradle and for me it is much easier to build only one subproject, not the whole tree every time and ofcourse to see Eclipse Ctrl+space helps.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project two, and left click on Properties.

[image]

Left click on Java Build Path.  Left click on Add Class Folder.

[image]

Check the class folder (bin) from project one.  Left click on OK.

Back on the Java Build Path dialog, left click on OK.

Comment: The first project is only code it does not have any bin directory only sourcees. SO if I do what you say I can tik only src folder and then nothing happes. Project two is empty? Why?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your second project's properties, to `Java Build Path`, then to the `Source` tab, and click on `Link Source...` button. There, click on `Browse...` button and select the `src` folder of your first project. This will allow you to change the source files from either project, and compile them from either project as well.

[image]